# Lagrange multipliers example with sympy - all minima but one maxima.

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

Consider the following optimization problem:

Minimize $x^3+y^3$

Subject to: $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$

On the boundary of the constraint, we can consider $x=\cos\theta$ and $y=\sin\theta$.

Then, the objective function becomes $\cos^3\theta+\sin^3\theta$. Plotting it with $\theta$, we get the following graph:

[image]

It's clear that the local minima $\frac{\pi}{4}$, $\pi$ and $\frac{3 \pi}{2}$.

Now, I want to get the local minima of the constrained optimization problem above using Lagrange multipliers.

The Lagrangian becomes: $L(x,y,\lambda) = x^3+y^3-\lambda(-x^2-y^2+1)$. And the KKT conditions (equations 12.30 in the book by [Nocedal and Wright](http://www.bioinfo.org.cn/~wangchao/maa/Numerical_Optimization.pdf)) yield:

$$3x^2+2\lambda x = 0 \tag{1}$$
$$3y^2+2\lambda y = 0 \tag{2}$$
$$x^2+y^2 \leq 1 \tag{3}$$
$$\lambda(x^2+y^2-1)=0 \tag{4}$$
$$\lambda \geq 0 \tag{5}$$

Now, we convert these into a system of polynomial equations. First, we replace $\lambda$ by $\lambda^2$ so we don't have to worry about $\lambda \geq 0$ and eliminate equation (5). Next, we convert equation (3) into an equality by introducing a dummy variable.

$$x^2+y^2-1=-\kappa^2 \tag{6}$$

Since $\kappa^2 \geq 0$ for real $\kappa$, this is equivalent to (3). 
Now, I plug equations (1), (2), (6) and (4) into sympy's polynomial equation solver:

```
from sympy import *
x, y, z, l, m, k = symbols('x y z l m k')
solve([Eq(3*x**2+2*x*l**2,0),
   Eq(3*y**2+2*y*l**2,0),
   Eq(x**2+y**2+k**2,1),
   Eq(x**2*l+y**2*l-l,0)], [x,y,l,k])
```

This produces the following solutions to this system:

```
[(-1, 0, -sqrt(6)/2, 0),
 (-1, 0, sqrt(6)/2, 0),
 (0, -1, -sqrt(6)/2, 0),
 (0, -1, sqrt(6)/2, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, -1),
 (0, 0, 0, 1),
 (0, 1, -sqrt(6)*I/2, 0),
 (0, 1, sqrt(6)*I/2, 0),
 (1, 0, -sqrt(6)*I/2, 0),
 (1, 0, sqrt(6)*I/2, 0),
 (-sqrt(2)/2, -sqrt(2)/2, -2**(1/4)*sqrt(3)/2, 0),
 (-sqrt(2)/2, -sqrt(2)/2, 2**(1/4)*sqrt(3)/2, 0),
 (sqrt(2)/2, sqrt(2)/2, -2**(1/4)*sqrt(3)*I/2, 0),
 (sqrt(2)/2, sqrt(2)/2, 2**(1/4)*sqrt(3)*I/2, 0)]
```

Any solution that involves imaginary numbers for $\lambda$ or $\kappa$ should be ignored since we require their squares to be $\geq 0$.

This gives us $(-1,0)$ which corresponds to $\pi$ in the graph above and this is a local minima, $(0,-1)$ which corresponds to $\frac{3 \pi}{2}$ in the graph above and this corresponds to a local minima as well. Next, we have $(0,0)$ and this corresponds to an inflection point at the very center of the feasible region. And finally, $(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ which corresponds to $\frac{5 \pi}{4}$. Herein lies the problem. All the points before this, clearly corresponded to local minima. But this one actually corresponds to a local maxima as can be seen in the graph above.

So it would seem the KKT conditions are picking all the local minima, but somehow swapping one of them with a local maxima. What am I missing here?

Comment: You do not have a convex program, so gradient KKT does not imply that the solutions from the Lagrangian are indeed optimal.

Comment: Sure, but they should still catch the local optima (minima in this case). They seem to miss $\frac{\pi}{4}$ which is clearly a local minima and catch $\frac{5 \pi}{4}$ which is a local maxima.

Comment: It is both. The KKT conditions seem to have excluded $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and included $\frac{5\pi}{4}$. Since the former is a minima and the latter is a maxima, they should have included the former and excluded the latter instead. This is surprising since all the other points they catch are indeed local minima or inflection points.

Comment: Yes I understand. Given that LICQ seems to be satisfied, I'm not sure why either we don't get that the KKT conditions don't pick this point up.

Comment: @RohitPandey The KKT equations differ when you are maximising or minimising. You will not get maxima and minima from the same set of equations.

Comment: @PierreCarre the problem is that given that the point $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$ satisfies LICQ (ie is regular) and is a local minimizer along the feasible unit circle, I believe it should be the case that KKT should pick this up.

Comment: The introduction of slack variables in the way was done doesn't change the problem essence. We still have a Lagrangian stationary points determination problem. This includes **all** stationary points. After that, a final qualification is required.

Comment: @Cesareo doesn't having $\lambda$ non-negative mean that this point is a local minimizer? Either way, what seems to be more troubling is the question of where is the point $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$? It's missing from the solutions yet it is a regular point (at least satisfying LICQ) that's a local minimizer.

Comment: @rb612- it boils down to this; if you look at equations (1) and (2), it's clear that positive values of $x$ and $y$ can't satisfy them if $\lambda>0$. But that is exactly what we get for the point $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$

Comment: $\lambda$ can't be forced to assume a positive value. With that we are forcing the directional choice in the condition $\nabla f +\lambda\nabla g=0$ .

Comment: @Cesareo I understand that is the case for Lagrange multipliers with only equality constraints, as we can have negative Lagrange multipliers. However, here we construct the Lagrangian with an inequality constraint. Shouldn't it be the case that this point $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$ satisfies our KKT conditions, with one of those conditions being $\lambda \geq 0$?

Comment: The slack variable $\kappa$ has the purpose to transform the inequality into an equality.

Comment: @Cesareo ah yes. However wouldn't solving by hand without $\kappa$ give the same answer, still missing the local minimizer in question despite it having the inequality constraint?

Comment: Although the point is a minimiser on the boundary, it is not a minimiser when we consider the whole feasible set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, since the only critical point in the interior of the feasible set is a saddle point, all local maxima and minima will occur on the boundary. In this sense it is enough to use Lagrange multipliers handling only the equality constraint. However, if you really want to use the KKT conditions, keep in mind that:

1. If $a \in D$ is a local minimiser (some regularity assumptions are require), it satisfies

$$
\begin{cases} 3x^2 -2 \lambda x = 0\\ 3y^2 - 2 \lambda y = 0\\ x^2+y^2 \leq 1 \\\lambda \leq 0 \\ \lambda (x^2+y^2-1) = 0 \end{cases}
$$

2. If $a \in D$ is a local maximiser (again, some regularity assumptions are require), it satisfies

$$
\begin{cases} 3x^2 -2 \lambda x = 0\\ 3y^2 - 2 \lambda y = 0\\ x^2+y^2 \leq 1 \\\lambda \ge 0 \\ \lambda (x^2+y^2-1) = 0 \end{cases}
$$

Solving these two systems you will get all the candidates to local minimiser and maximiser. The point is that when you fix the sign of the multiplier you a restricting yourself to find either minima or maxima.

Keep in mind that these are only necessary conditions.

EDIT:

After solving both systems, you will see that the candidates to minimisers are
$$
(0,0), (-1,0), (0,-1), (-\sqrt{2}/2, -\sqrt{2}/2)
$$

and the candidates to maximisers are

$$
(0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (\sqrt{2}/2, \sqrt{2}/2)
$$

Looking at the behaviour of the objective function on the boundary and on the straight line $y=x$, you can see that $(0,0)$, $(\sqrt{2}/2, \sqrt{2}/2)$ and $(-\sqrt{2}/2, -\sqrt{2}/2)$ are saddle points. The local maximisers are $(0,1),(1,0)$ and the local minimisers are $(0,-1),(-1,0)$. Compactness arguments and the inexistence of irregular points actually allows to show that these are the global maximisers/minimisers.

Comment: The problem is that the local minimum $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$ doesn't satisfy 1 despite it being a local minimizer and (from what I can see) satisfying the regularity assumptions.

Comment: For 1 to be satisfied, $\lambda\leq 0$, and here you found a $\lambda$ which is positive. This is the problem that OP and I are trying to solve. This point is a local minimum but it only satisfies number 2 for your answer.

Comment: how about the plot from the original question? It shows $\frac{\pi}{4}$ as a local minimizer. I'm trying to verify, it's possible that the point is a saddle point. We can determine this by looking at the Hessian and seeing if it's indefinite.

Comment: @rb612 The KKT conditions are necessary conditions, they are not sufficient. The issue here is that this point is not actually a minimiser... Although you reach a minimum when you approach the point along the border, you reach a maximum if you move along $y=x$ for instance. In fact, solving (1) and (2) you actually show that the point cannot be either a minimum or a maximum.

Comment: Yes, this is the key. I was thinking that it was a local minimizer given the picture but I neglected to check if it was actually a local minimizer. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: Thanks, my faith in optimization techniques is restored :) On a side note, it seems that some saddle points are caught by the minima conditions while others are caught by the maxima conditions. Is there a way to predict for a given saddle point which of the conditions it will end up satisfying?

Comment: Also, would it be fair to say that (0,0) is an inflection point, not a saddle point.

Comment: @RohitPandey This entirely depends on the definitions you are considering. For functions of several variables it is very unusual to even  use the term "inflection point". On the other hand, the definition of a saddle point is simply a critical point that is not a local max/min. The term saddle point does not necessarily refer to the geometric configuration of a saddle but rather to its main feature: the center of the saddle can be a minimum or a maximum, depending on how you are approaching the point.

Answer (score 2):

Calling

$$
f(x,y) = x^3+y^3\\
g(x,y) = x^2+y^2-1
$$

we have the Lagrangian

$$
L(x,y,\lambda,\epsilon) = f+\lambda(g+\epsilon^2)
$$

So the stationary points are obtained by solving

$$
\nabla L = 0 = \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 \epsilon ^2+x^2+y^2-1 \\
 3 x^2+2 \lambda  x \\
 3 y^2+2 \lambda  y \\
 2 \epsilon  \lambda  \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

with results

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccccc}
\lambda & x & y & \epsilon & f(x,y) & \det(H_g)\\
 \frac{3}{2} & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 \frac{3}{2} & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -\frac{3}{2} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -\frac{3}{2} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 \frac{3}{2 \sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 12 \sqrt{2} \\
 -\frac{3}{2 \sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -12 \sqrt{2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

where $\det(H_g)$ represents the bordered Hessian determinant

$$
H_g = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 2 x & 2 y \\
 2 x & 6 x & 0 \\
 2 y & 0 & 6 y \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

needed to qualify the stationary points. So as we can verify, the  optimal points are at $(0,-1)$ and $(-1,0)$ as global minima and $(0,1), \ (1,0)$ as global maxima. the last two solutions cover local extrema. The first a local maximum and the last a local minimum

NOTE

Attached a plot showing the objective function level surface lines into the feasible region, showing in red the constraint gradient and in black the objective function gradient at each stationary point. At the maximum points the combination $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ has $\lambda > 0$ as well as the minimum we have $-\nabla f = \lambda f $ also with $\lambda > 0$

[image]

Attached the MATHEMATICA script to produce the shown graphics.

```
usols = {{x -> -1, y -> 0, s1 -> 0, l1 -> 3/2}, {x -> 0, y -> -1, 
s1 -> 0, l1 -> 3/2}, {x -> 0, y -> 0, s1 -> -1, l1 -> 0}, {x -> 0,
 y -> 1, s1 -> 0, l1 -> -(3/2)}, {x -> 1, y -> 0, s1 -> 0, 
l1 -> -(3/2)}, {x -> -(1/Sqrt[2]), y -> -(1/Sqrt[2]), s1 -> 0, 
l1 -> 3/(2 Sqrt[2])}, {x -> 1/Sqrt[2], y -> 1/Sqrt[2], s1 -> 0, 
l1 -> -(3/(2 Sqrt[2]))}};

toler = 0.000001;

\[Lambda] = Sqrt[2]/5;

xinf = -1.6;
yinf = -1.6;
xsup = 1.6;
ysup = 1.6;

f[x_, y_] := x^3 + y^3
g1[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 - 1
G = {g1[x, y]};
For [i = 1; ListaSols = {}; ListaVecs = {}, i <= Length[usols], i++,
  s = {s1} /. usols[[i]];
  For[j = 1, j <= Length[s], j++, If[Abs[s[[j]]] < toler,
    v = Grad[-G[[j]], {x, y}] /. usols[[i]];
    nv = Norm[v];
    If[nv > 0,
      p1 = {x, y} /. usols[[i]];
      p2 = p1 + \[Lambda] v/nv;
    AppendTo[ListaVecs, Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{p1, p2}]}]]]
 ]
];
 v = Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}] /. usols[[i]];
 nv = Norm[v];
 p1 = {x, y} /. usols[[i]];
 If[nv > 0,
   p2 = p1 + \[Lambda] v/nv;
   AppendTo[ListaVecs, Graphics[{Arrow[{p1, p2}]}]]];
   AppendTo[ListaSols, {{Red, PointSize[0.015], Point[p1]}}]
 ]

grp = ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, xinf, xsup}, {y, yinf, ysup}, 
RegionFunction -> ((g1[#1, #2] < 0) &), Contours -> 125, 
Epilog -> ListaSols, PlotPoints -> 50];
Show[grp, ListaVecs, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Comment: How do we reconcile this with equation (13) in Nocedal and Wright (linked in the question). It seems like they require $\lambda>0$.

Comment: @RohitPandey this too is where I have the trouble with the solution here. It's that $\lambda \geq 0$ for the KKT conditions to be satisfied, and the fact that the point is a regular point satisfying the constraint qualifications I believe means it's necessary that it follows the KKT conditions.

Comment: Agree. The core of this question is - why don't the KKT conditions (as described in the book linked) catch the $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ solution.

Comment: The KKT conditions can be understood as the possibility to obtain a convex objective function gradient representation, from the constraints gradients  at the qualification point. The sign of $\lambda$ depend on the minimization/maximization choice.

Comment: In this case, I framed the problem exactly as in chapter 12 of the Nocedal and Wright book (which assume a minimization problem). So, the conditions in equation (12.30) which are solutions to the problem they framed, should have caught all the local minima. No?

Comment: Yeah I'm fairly confident that satisfying the KKT conditions for inequality constraints in the exact way that it's formatted (removing the slack variable $\kappa$) only will be satisfied for $\lambda \geq 0$. It's one thing if there's a violated condition that causes the KKT conditions to not be satisfied, which would make the most sense, however I believe the sign matters here (ie $\lambda \geq 0$). The dual feasibility condition is a component of the KKT conditions, and I can't find the constraint qualification that would violate it here, though I'm sure I'm missing an edge case.

Comment: Please. See attached note.

Comment: @Cesareo thanks for the visualization. However $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$ is a local minimum, as you correctly stated earlier right before your note, not a local maximum so it's gradient vector should be pointing opposite like you stated. So the sign of $\lambda$ is still opposite what KKT says for local minimizers.

Comment: Yes. You are right. The flaw is that the constraint should be considered $g \le 0$ and thus the gradient correct representation is with opposite sign. I will fix it ASAP.

Comment: Thanks @Cesareo — this still leaves us wondering the core part of the question, why is the KKT conditions giving us a local maximizer instead of the local minimizer?

Comment: The $KKT$ are normally defined for a standardized problem such as $\min f \ \mbox{s. t. }\  \ g\le 0$ To focus maximization problems we should consider $\min -f \ \mbox{s. t. }\  \ g\le 0$ etc...

Comment: @Cesareo - thanks for the answer, the plot you included is gorgeous, BTW. Any chance you can share the code you used to draw it?

Comment: @RohitPandey Attached a code fragment in MATHEMATICA to produce the shown graphics.